# What are the differences between Binance Chain and Polygon?

Tags: dapps

I have some experience using Matic, which works just like Ethereum, I point metamask to Matic and boom, I can publish smart contracts, use the explorer, use the gas station, etc.

Now I have a project to deploy to the Binance chain. Does it work the same way? I see that ERC20 is called BEP20, is there a difference in the smart contract code? Are there any peculiarities of the network I have to take into consideration when launching a custom smart contract for ERC721 conditional minting?

Answer (score 1):

Theyre both the same from a programming standoint (i.e they both are EVM compatible).  BEP20 and ERC20 are the exact same. Im not super familiar with erc721 so i cant Say for sure there isnt any differences but i dont see a reason why they would be one. Gas on the BSC costs more than on polygon though, you might want to be more careful about gas usage when coding for the BSC (it's still reasonable though, its not ETH mainnet lol)